# Uploading HD Video to Facebook Group

Tags: facebook, video

Can anyone explain why Facebook will not allow group members to view video I have uploaded in HD? If I view the video on my timeline, it is in HD, when I view it on the group page, it is in low res and the HD button is not there.

Comment: What's the current behavior? And the question as you asked it doesn't really fit here - "can anyone explain why facebook.." instead, it's better asking why members of the groups can't watch it in HD, or how to make them see it in HD